# INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint after first 1k insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to insert about 30k rows of data into a database.  The first thousand rows go through without any problem but after that I keep getting the error "INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint"

I am inserting into one table first getting the identity and then using that as a fk for the other table.  Code looks like

```
 insert into PYMT_HIST(PAR_NUM,BILL_NUM,RCPT_NUM,TAX_YR,TOT_AMT_DUE,TOT_PD,PD_DATE,PD_BY,MUNI_DIST_ID)
        values (@par_num,@BILL_NUM,@RCTP_NUM,@TAX_YR,@TOT_AMT_DUE,@TOT_PD,(Convert(datetime,@PD_DATE)),@PD_BY,@MUNI_DIST_ID);
    set @pymt_hist_id = @@identity


    IF  @REAL_ESTATE > 0

        insert into PYMT_HIST_DETL(PYMT_HIST_ID,AMT_PD,FIN_TXN_LN_TY_ID)
                values(@pymt_hist_id,@REAL_ESTATE,1);
```

Comment: You could print to the output the values you are trying to insert and then verify why you get a error for those particular values.

Comment: This probably isn't the issue, but you probably want to use SCOPE_IDENTITY() instead of @@identity if your are using SQL Server 2005 or later. You want to make sure the identity value you are getting is from the current session (not from someone else running another query that is inserting into the same table). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

Comment: @rsbarro - The problem with `@@identity` is triggers not concurrent transactions.

Comment: @martin, according to the documentation: "SCOPE_IDENTITY and @@IDENTITY return the last identity values that are generated in any table in the current session. However, SCOPE_IDENTITY returns values inserted only within the current scope; @@IDENTITY is not limited to a specific scope." Doesn't that mean it would be a problem with concurrent transactions or am I reading that wrong?

Comment: @rsbarro - Your quote says "... return the last identity values that are generated in any table in **the current** session."...

Comment: @Martin Yea, you're right. Should have read the documentation further. I always thought that SCOPE_IDENTITY was preferred, though. Is it true that it only matters if you're using triggers then?

Comment: @rsbarro - I presume that executing any sort of child batch such as `EXEC stored_proc` or `EXEC ('dynamic_sql')` can alter the value of `@@identity` but not `scope_identity`. Not sure though as I only really use `scope_identity` and I would always assign from it straight after the `insert` statement.

Comment: @Martin OK, that makes sense. I never really run into issues with @@identity because I always use SCOPE_IDENTITY as well. At least now I have a better idea why I'm doing that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Scope_Identity() function instead of @@Identity.  @@Identity has global scope and could be getting changed outside the scope of the work you are doing.